# Django - Send notification to user after new like

Tags: python, django, ajax, django-messages

I'm searching for a method to notify an user if another user liked his/her post.
For example instagram is giving you an alert: "this_user liked your post".

Is there a way to do with djangos integrated messages framework? So far I got the logic for like a post (simple post request). I want to send the notification to the author of the post so after `post.save()` method.

Someone know how to do?

Comment: I don't think this system is designed to send messages to a *different user.* I would create a database model to store the notifications.

Comment: Hey check out this guy on youtube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_JKWYkz597c&list=PLPSM8rIid1a3TkwEmHyDALNuHhqiUiU5A&index=13

Answer (score 1):

You can't use messages framework for notify, messages works in request/response cycle. maybe [**onesignal**](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs) is useful in your case.

[onesignal-sdk](https://pypi.org/project/onesignal-sdk/) is a python client library